# array of strings vs array of objects java

Tags: java, types, variadic-functions

I came across this section of commented code on StackOverflow. It will throw a Runtime exception. The second part (the un-commented section) will work. I am not able to find the difference between the two, as both methods are returning arrays of Objects. Maybe I am missing some basic understanding. Can you please help me?

```
public class Safevarargs {

/*  
    static <Object> Object[] asArray(Object... args) {
        return args;
    }

    static <Object> Object[] arrayOfTwo( Object a, Object b) {
        return asArray(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] bar = arrayOfTwo("hi", "mom");
    }
*/

    static <Object> Object[] display(Object... args) {
        return args;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] str =  display("hi", "mom");
        System.out.print(str[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: It is EXTREMELY bad practice to use a name like `Object` for a generic type variable.

Comment: You have some needless repetition. There's no way `asArray` is erroneous but not `display`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having a problem with casting. When you use the part

```
static <Object> Object[] display(Object... args)
```

what the compiler is actually seeing is

```
static <Object> Object[] display(Object[]... args)
```

then it further converts it to this

```
static <Object> Object[] display(List[]... args)
```

This might allow values that shouldn't be in there

lets say you make an object array of string and try adding an int to it. This would causes a problem with the different types. You might want to rework it without using the generic Object.

Alternatively you could use the @SafeVarargs tag.

Comment: The compiler sees `Object[]` when looking at `Object...` and at no point is `List` involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting situation here. In the first instance, Java complains about casting from an object array to a string array.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

In the second case, it handles it just fine. The issue seems to be type erasure. When `asArray` returns, it's returning an array typed based on its parameters. That information is erased within the context of `arrayOfTwo`, where the type simply becomes `Object[]`, and the fact that the contents are strings is no longer available.

Have a look at [this post](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html) on type erasure and non-reifiable types, and the implications on varargs. It does provide some context on the warning which the code generates, about "possible heap pollution":

> Safevarargs.java:11: warning: [unchecked] Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type Object 
>       static  Object[] display(Object... args) { 
>                                                  ^
>     where Object is a type-variable:
>       Object extends java.lang.Object declared in method display(Object...)

From the documentation:

> Heap pollution occurs when a variable of a parameterized type refers to an object that is not of that parameterized type.

Answer (score 0):

To explain this issue, we just need to know how the generic work in java.  *the compiler uses the generic type information internally during the process of compilation, generating type-related errors as it processes the sources. Then, once the validation is done, the compiler generates type-erased byte code, with all references to generic types replaced with their respective type erasure.*

in your second example, the it is compile to string during the compile time. but in your first example, since the  asArray is called by another generic method, it will be compile into Object during compile time. As a result, in the running time, the Object[] can not be cast to String[] which will throw class cast exception. hope this can help you